# oracle search word in string

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to search a word in string in ORACLE in which string is comma separated.
Eg. String is ('MF1,MF2,MF3') and now I want to search whether 'MF' exists in that or not.
If I am using instr('MF1,MF2,MF3','MF') it will give wrong result since I want to search Full MF in MF1 or MF2 or MF3.

Comment: Not sure why INSTR() doesn't cut the mustard.  Could you edit your question to explain a bit more?

Answer (score 1):

Try ..

```
instr(','||'MF1,MF2,MF3'||',',',MF,')
```

or more generically

```
instr(','||col||',' ,  ','||val||',')
```

Answer (score 0):

If the incoming string is always in this form:

```
('X,Y,Z,...')
```

You could do something like this - replace the quotes with commas, then search for the criterion surrounded with commas:

```
DECLARE
   in_str VARCHAR2(4000) := '(''MF1,MF2,MF3'')';
   criterion VARCHAR2(100) := 'MF';
BEGIN
   IF INSTR(REPLACE(in_str,'''',','), ',' || criterion || ',') > 0 THEN
      dbms_output.put_line('found!');
   END IF;
END;
```

So the above would say "found!" for `MF1` but not for `MF`.